# Cannot create Access file in C#

Tags: c#

I called this method and it turns out an access file with only the first four tables and the error message came out with the message box of the try-catch. This method was ok before I added the table6, table7 and some keys. Is there any solution?

```
public void createStockAccess()
{
    ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
    ADOX.Table table = new ADOX.Table();
    ADOX.Table table2 = new ADOX.Table();
    ADOX.Table table3 = new ADOX.Table();
    ADOX.Table table4 = new ADOX.Table();
    ADOX.Table table5 = new ADOX.Table();
    ADOX.Table table6 = new ADOX.Table();
    ADOX.Table table7 = new ADOX.Table();
    //Create the table and it's fields. 
    table.Name = "Gold";
    table.Columns.Append("Weight", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adDouble);
    table.Columns.Append("DollarPerGram", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adCurrency);

    table2.Name = "Diamond";
    table2.Columns.Append("Size", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 4);
    table2.Columns.Append("Quantity", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, 4);
    table2.Columns.Append("Carat", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adDouble);
    table2.Columns.Append("DollarPerCarat", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adCurrency);
    table2.Keys.Append("DiamondPK", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary, "Size");

    table3.Name = "Parts";
    table3.Columns.Append("Number", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 10);
    table3.Columns.Append("Weight", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adDouble);
    table3.Columns.Append("DollarPerGram", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adCurrency);
    table3.Keys.Append("PartsPK", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary, "Number");

    table4.Name = "Jewel";
    table4.Columns.Append("Number", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 9);
    table4.Columns.Append("TypeNumber", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 10);
    table4.Columns.Append("Manufacturer", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 30);
    table4.Columns.Append("ManuCost", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adCurrency);
    table4.Columns.Append("Price", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adCurrency);
    table4.Columns.Append("GoldColor", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 10);
    table4.Columns.Append("GoldCarat", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 3);
    table4.Columns.Append("GoldWeight", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adDouble);
    table4.Columns.Append("Type", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 20);
    table4.Columns.Append("Cost", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adCurrency);
    table4.Columns.Append("Status", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 15);
    table4.Columns["Manufacturer"].Attributes = ColumnAttributesEnum.adColNullable;
    table4.Columns["ManuCost"].Attributes = ColumnAttributesEnum.adColNullable;
    table4.Columns["GoldCarat"].Attributes = ColumnAttributesEnum.adColNullable;
    table4.Columns["GoldWeight"].Attributes = ColumnAttributesEnum.adColNullable;
    table4.Columns["Cost"].Attributes = ColumnAttributesEnum.adColNullable;
    table4.Keys.Append("PrimaryKey", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary, "Number", "JewelDiamond", "Number");            

    table5.Name = "JewelDiamond";
    table5.Columns.Append("Number", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 9);
    table5.Columns.Append("Size", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 4);
    table5.Columns.Append("Quantity", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, 4);
    table5.Columns.Append("Carat", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adDouble);
    table5.Columns.Append("Type", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 20);
    table5.Keys.Append("PrimaryKeyJD", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary, "Number");
    table5.Keys["PrimaryKeyJD"].Columns.Append("Size", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 4);
    table5.Keys.Append("ForeignKeyJD", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyForeign, "Number", "Jewel", "Number");

    table6.Name = "Type";
    table6.Columns.Append("TypeNumber", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 10);
    table6.Columns.Append("Picture", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 150);
    table6.Columns["Picture"].Attributes = ColumnAttributesEnum.adColNullable;
    table6.Keys.Append("typePK", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary, "TypeNumber");

    table7.Name = "TypeInfo";
    table7.Columns.Append("TypeNumber", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 10);
    table7.Columns.Append("Size", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 4);
    table7.Columns.Append("Quantity", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adDouble);
    table7.Keys.Append("infoPK", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary, "TypeNumber");
    table7.Keys["infoPK"].Columns.Append("Size", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 4);
    table7.Keys.Append("infoFK", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyForeign, "TypeNumber", "Type", "TypeNumber");

    table4.Keys.Append("ForeignKey", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyForeign, "TypeNumber", "Type", "TypeNumber");
    try
    {
        cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=Stock.mdb; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5");
        cat.Tables.Append(table);
        cat.Tables.Append(table2);
        cat.Tables.Append(table3);
        cat.Tables.Append(table4);
        cat.Tables.Append(table5);
        cat.Tables.Append(table6);
        cat.Tables.Append(table7);
        //Now Close the database
        Interop.Adodb.Connection con = cat.ActiveConnection as Interop.Adodb.Connection;
        if (con != null)
            con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("cannot create stock database.");
    }
    cat = null;
}
```

Comment: What is the exception message and stack trace? Always provide `ex.Message` and `ex.StackTrace` on error catch - that's the key to problem solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always provide exception message and stacktrace on error catch - that's the key to problem solution.

As I guess, the most probable problem is the following line of code:

```
table4.Keys.Append("PrimaryKey", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary, "Number", "JewelDiamond", "Number");
```

You add a **primary key** and define related table and column. Probably, you just missed this when you copied your code.

It should be:

```
table4.Keys.Append("PrimaryKey", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary, "Number");
```

Comment: It still does not work. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040E3C) comes out and the error is at ADOX.Tables.Append(Object Item)

Comment: @TinlokCheung Post the full stack trace as edit to your question, please.

Comment: I finally solve the problem by changing the position of cat.Tables.Append(table4); and cat.Tables.Append(table6);

Comment: @TinlokCheung Nice to hear it. You can post it as an answer and accept it instead of my one :)